# Problems with replacing missing values in a DataFrame with Julia 0.6.2

Tags: csv, julia, missing-data

So, I will preface this by saying that I am new I the Julia language and trying to work through some tutorials on handling data sets. But I seem to be hitting a problem with handling missing values and cannot seem to figure out what is wrong.

Specifically:

I have a 11 x 5 DataFrame containing some test data (with missing values) that I load into Julia using:

`D = CSV.read("name.csv"; rows_for_type_detect = 10);`

This works fine, but in order to actually use the data, I need to handle the missing values. Skipping them entirely works just fine, but ideally I'd like to replace them with something reasonable (mean, etc). In theory, this looks like it should be straightforward from the documentation for "Missings". However, as a simple example, if I run:

`Missings.replace(D[:Col4], 1)`

I would expect this command to replace all missing values in Col4 with the value 1. Instead, it appears to run successfully and I get this output (not an error):

`Missings.EachReplaceMissing{Array{Union{Int64, Missings.Missing},1},Int64}(Union{Int64, Missings.Missing}
replacement -> 1`

First, I am having some issues understanding this output. There is more than one missing value in Col4. So, right from the start, this is incorrect ("replacement -> 1" ?). However, not only did it not replace one value, it failed to replace ANY values. The DataFrame D remains unchanged, missing values intact.

Anyone have any ideas what is wrong here? (Or alternative suggestions on how to accomplish replacing missing values in a DataFrame in Julia?)

I am running Julia 0.6.2.

Comment: Just FYI if `Missings.replace` *were* to modify the data frame D then it would (by convention) be called `Missings.replace!`, an ! indicating that a function mutates its arguments (usually the first) :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that `Missings.replace` creates an iterator.
You need to write

```
collect(Missings.replace(D[:Col4], 1)
```

to create a new vector. It will not update the column in the `DataFrame` though. It will be a new vector you have to assign it back to a `DataFrame`.

To change it in place you can do either a loop:

```
for r in eachrow(D)
    ismissing(r[:Col4]) && (r[:Col4] = 1)
end
```

or this (which is simpler but makes an allocation):

```
D[:Col4][ismissing.(D[:Col4])] = 1
```

Maybe there is something simpler but those are the first options that come to my mind.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Both your suggestions work perfectly!